How to Deploy a node js site in go daddy
I bought a site in godaddy with a shared hosting server. I used react.js for frontend and node.js in backend. I bought economy plan. And node js software is not in available in go daddy plan. I install the node using this blog https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-manage-node-using-nvm-on-godaddy-server/ .But i couldn't deploy the node.js app in my c panel but my react frontend is working fine.
The error i get this when i try to run my login page frontend + backend in terminal. Thanks in advance.
 node run
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/xtweaq6qn0y9/public_html/run'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.12.2


You have a SHARED hosting server.
This guide talks about a DEDICATED VPS server.
You have to get a dedicated server to be able to install things like node on it.

I have installed node js in that but i could not link to domain and run the application. I   need the backend for the login page domain_name/login page i tried using application manager after that i got the error displayed above
